# Regular Expression in Django URLs

Tags: python, regex, django

i am trying to add url to my view but it throws an exception

"^(?p[0-9]+)/$" is not a valid regular expression: unknown extension ?p at position 2

view url in URLs file

```
url(r'^(?p<studentID>[0-9]+)/$',views.Student,name ='Student' )
```

Comment: Should be a capital `P`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` should be uppercase:

```
url(r'^(?P<studentID>[0-9]+)/$',views.Student,name ='Student' )
```